# FormData gets uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a form submission through AJAX using jQuery. I have the following code:

```
$("#myForm-form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: { 
            'eoss': 'indexEOSS',
            'form': 'myForm',
            'values': createJSON(), 
            'formData': formData 
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            eval(data);
            myFormForm(data);
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }); 
    return false
});
```

However I get this:

> GET http://localhost/EOSS2/request.php?[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

When I remove `processData: false` and `contentType: false` I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

What should I do?

Comment: It should be a POST request

Comment: why? it cannot be GET request?

Comment: @durisvk no, when dealing with `FormData` you cannot use GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly your error message indicates that you're sending a GET request, which does not work with `FormData`. Using POST would seem the most applicable in this case.

Secondly, you cannot send `FormData` in an object as jQuery will attempt to URL encode it which will lead to issues. Instead use the `append()` method to add information to your `FormData` object. Try this:

```
$("#myForm-form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData($form[0]);
    formData.append('eoss', 'indexEOSS');
    formData.append('form', 'myForm');
    formData.append('values', createJSON());

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'), // change the attribute in HTML or hardcode to 'post'
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // eval(data); < never, ever use eval()
            myFormForm(data);
        },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank You very much, this answer was very helpful and now it works :) Thank You one more time :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help